# setFocus not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript, html

Im using form_name.textbox.focus() and it working fine in IE but not in mozilla. Can someone tell me how to handle this? this for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a non-standard IE behavior that turns all elements with IDs into global variables.
Since Firefox does not do this, `form_name` is `undefined`.

Change it to

```
document.getElementById("ID of <input> element").focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Give these a go:

```
document.form_name.textbox.focus()
document.form_name[ "textbox" ].focus()
```

Comment: Note that `form_name` is not the `<form>`'s `ID`.